# HTML 5 validations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was checking out this [example at tutsplus](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/bring-your-forms-up-to-date-with-css3-and-html5-validation/) and this is what I found.

- In linux **Chrome 9** validation didn't work at all. Have I disabled anything?
- In **Opera 11** name was not validated but validation worked for all other fields. Why was this so?

http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/214_html5_form_validation/demo/index.html

*Is there any tool/script to make HTML 5 forms to work cross browser?*

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+form+cross+browser

Comment: You should really learn to use question marks (?). They are important punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching for over a hour i have found a few things.

1. for required attribute to work  the field needs to have a name which was missing in the example
2. I found http://code.google.com/p/webforms2/ that helps a bit
3. Validation support in 7.0 was disabled and re-enabled in 10.0 [source(see formnovalidate)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/input#Compatibility)